# Data does not display when making loop statement in datagridview control

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview

I had datagridview control which retrieves data from database. I had my code to do that, but no data apeared in gridview. I made a break point in the loop but when on   `DataGridViewTextBoxCell Number = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)DGCategory.Rows[i].Cells[l];`
 datagrid view apeared with no data

```
private void getcategory()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < DGCategory.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < DGCategory.Rows[i].Cells.Count; l++)
                {
                    DataGridViewTextBoxCell Number = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)DGCategory.Rows[i].Cells[l];
                    DataGridViewTextBoxCell Category = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)DGCategory.Rows[i].Cells[l];
                    DataGridViewTextBoxCell Parent = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)DGCategory.Rows[i].Cells[l];
                    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell Active = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)DGCategory.Rows[i].Cells[l];
                    DataGridViewTextBoxCell AddDate = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)DGCategory.Rows[i].Cells[l];

                using (SqlConnection Con = GetConnection())
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_GetAllCategories", Con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlDataReader dr;
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Number.Value = dr["Number"].ToString();
                        Category.Value = dr["Category"].ToString();
                        Parent.Value = dr["Parent"].ToString();
                        Active.Value = dr["Active"].ToString();
                        AddDate.Value = dr["AddDate"].ToString();

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have no clue what your are trying to do with those loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want to get values from your database into a grid view .. use the following:
write your query in a String called "selectCommand" for example then use a dataset to get the results:

```
public DataSet GetSearchEmpResults(string emp_fn)
{
string selectCommand = @"select 
                                emp.first_name as 'First Name',
                                emp.last_name as 'Last Name'
                                from Employees emp
                                where emp.first_name = '" + emp_fn + "';";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectCommand, this.Connection);
DataSet ds = new DataSet("Results");
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
da.Fill(ds, "Results");
return ds;  
}
```

then in the data gridview code:

```
DataSet results = db.GetSearchEmpResults(fristName, lastName); //this depends on your results
dataGridViewResults.DataSource = results;
dataGridViewResults.DataMember = "Results";
```

the **dataGridViewResults** is the name of the data gridview you want your results yo appear in.
 Note that you should provide the connection to your database in order to receive the results.